# Tomcat with Eclipse: Made a copy of webapp and renamed, the context path does not change

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I had a webapp named `Test`, it was running some servlets on the path `/Test` , by default, taking the `appname` as the context path.

I made a copy of this project in Eclipse, and renamed it to `TestNew`, now when i run this on tomcat (from within eclipse) it still runs on `/Test`, though if i had created a new app, it would have run on `/TestNew`

I tried looking for the setting or the appname in `web.xml` , `pom.xml` etc, but i could not find the appropriate place to change this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly *how* did you make this copy?

Comment: Right click on existing project in eclipse and copy paste , then rename/refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to resolve the issue.
When we make a copy and rename the project, it doesn't update in certain places, specifically, in `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file.

So, just open the file and replace the old `appName` to new `appName` everwhere it appears. In my case,

```
<wb-module deploy-name="appName">
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/appName/target/classes"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="appName"/>
</wb-module>
```

and Done! 
Now tomcat from inside eclipse gets the correct name.

(Not sure whether we would have faced the same issue in an external tomcat deployment, as the .settings/file seems only relevant to eclipse)